# Prax - "Can't start application"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup *Prax* on Linux but whenever I point to http://market_place_api.dev I get the following error:

```
RVM project not found at: /media/pluralism/Data/market_place_api
I, [2016-03-14T16:30:10.286932 #30163]  INFO -- : Prax is ready to receive connections on :20559 and :20558.
I, [2016-03-14T16:30:29.961939 #30163]  INFO -- : Spawning application 'market_place_api' [/media/pluralism/Data/market_place_api]
/home/pluralism/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:250:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/pluralism/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/pluralism/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/pluralism/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/pluralism/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
^CI, [2016-03-14T16:30:35.760481 #30163]  INFO -- : Forcing restart of market_place_api (/media/pluralism/Data/market_place_api)
```

What could be wrong with my installation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `bundler` gem is missing. Install it with `gem install bundler` and see if it helps.

Comment: How did you install `prax`? Also what command were you running when you get this error?

Comment: I followed the instructions as stated in http://ysbaddaden.github.io/prax/. I was running the command _prax start -f_
What could be causing the "RVM project not found at:" error?

Comment: Are you using `rvm`? If yes, have you setup the configuration for `prax` to work with `rvm` as mentioned at https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax/wiki/Ruby-Version-Managers ?

Comment: Yes, I have the .praxconfig file in the $HOME folder. I'm probably setting up the app in a wrong way. Let me check that please. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue. I also have this problem and I google around but still cannot find the solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into a similar problem. It seems like they might've built their gem using a different version of `rubygems`. The only solution I found was upgrading rubygems, `gem update --system`.

Comment: My local gem version was 2.4.5.1, after the update, I'm at 2.6.2 (which works)

Comment: I've figured out what I was doing wrong. The problem was that my project wasn't a RVM project. Once I created a gemset it worked out of the box.